# Opening a new form, closing the old one C#

Tags: c#, forms, new-operator

I'm kinda new to C# and I'm doing self study by trying to make a program with a variety of functions to teach myself how to work with C#. I usually look at the internet if I don't know something but this has been driving me crazy.

I remember in the very beginning i started this that I wanted to open a form and close the old one, but when i closed the new form, the old form would reappear again, and other weird varieties of this issue. this.Hide() didn't seem to do anything either.

Currently for opening a new form I'm using this code, but it feels like there should be something with 1 line of code for something as simple as opening a form...
My question is if there is.

```
    private void OpenMainForm()
    {
        MainForm frm2 = new MainForm();
        frm2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(frm2_FormClosed);
        frm2.Show();

        // Since this.Hide() for some reason doesn't work, i'll have to do this crap
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }

    private void frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to hide your main window when you're in the secondary one, you should use the `ShowDialog()` method. With that, you won't even need the `form_closed event`.

Your code should look like:

```
private void OpenMainForm()
{
    MainForm frm2 = new MainForm();
    this.Hide();           //Hide the main form before showing the secondary
    frm2.ShowDialog();     //Show secondary form, code execution stop until frm2 is closed
    this.Show();           //When frm2 is closed, continue with the code (show main form)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this code:

```
public static void ThreadProc()
{
    Form2 f; 
    Application.Run(new Form2());
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
    t.Start();
    this.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for me

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Show();
frm.Activate();
this.Hide();
```

but if you want to close the whole application from Form2...you have to add `Application.Exit();` in `FormClosing` event of Form2

Comment: It's a very old question though but i just came across and tried it out but Application.Exit(); is not working in case of main form (Form1) is hidden.

Comment: I just re-confirmed it, works fine for me. Any error it throws for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide old form as below.

```
private void frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still do the same thing, when you close the new form, it just pops up the old form won't it?

Comment: If you hide new form and then later open it again with `new` keywords then it'll appear newly and `Garbage Collector` will dispose the unreferenced form, hope you've got me, thanks for your time.

Comment: .. That is so weird. the problem before was that this.Hide() just didn't do shit, now I'm putting in the exact same code as before with this.Hide() and it does work, so i don't have to use that weird code anymore oo thanks.